# Add a new column to a Pandas DataFrame by using values in another column to lookup values in a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, ipython

How do I add a column to a Pandas DataFrame, by multiplying an existing column by a factor from an external dictionary looked up using values from a second column in the same DataFrame as keys?

I have a `pd.DataFrame` dataframe `df` roughly of the form

```
    code    blah...     year    nominal
0   T.rrr   blah...     2012-13     2.08
1   J.rrr   blah...     2008-09     1.09
2   1320    blah...     2008-09     1.38
3   1310    blah...     2010-11     1.20
4   1130    blah...     2010-11     1.22
```

I also have these `factors` as a dictionary:

```
factors = {'2008-09': 1.11075, '2010-11': 1.02947, '2012-13': 1.}
```

I want to add a column by multiplying each nominal value by the appropriate factor, which I want to look up in the external `factors` dictionary using a second column `df['year']` in the dataframe `df` as a key

```
df['real'] = df['nominal'] * factors[df['year']]
```

or

```
df['real'] = df.nominal * factors[df.year]
```

but both of those produce errors. I also tried things like

```
def nominal_to_real(df, nom_col='nominal', year_col='year', factors=factors):
    return df[nom_col] * factors[df[year_col]]

df['real] = df.apply(nominal_to_real, axis=1)
```

which produces the following error

> /Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/**main**.py:5:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

What am I doing wrong? Surely this should be simple...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Use the `map` method of Series to look up in the dictionary:

```
df['nominal'] * df['year'].map(factors)
```

Comment: Thanks @brenbarn! You don't happen to also know how to store that to `df['real']` without getting that error? Do I need to create a separate series and then use `concat` to add it to the dataframe, or is there a way to do it all with one line? `df['real'] = df['nominal'] * df['year'].map(factors)` still errors. Much appreciated.

Comment: @amosoma: What is `df`?  Is it a slice of some other DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, it's a section of another DataFrame containing only rows with 'nominal' in particular units. Tks

Comment: Yes @brenbarn, it's a section of another DataFrame containing only rows with `nominal` in particular units. (Apologies if you got this reply more than once.) Tks

Comment: @amosoma: Okay, so the warning is because of that.  It doesn't matter how you try to set it; if you try to set values on that slice, you'll get that warning.  As I guess you found, you can get around it by doing the entire slice-and-and-assign in one giant line.  However, note that the "error" you're seeing is actually a *warning*; often the assignment will work just fine despite the warning.

Answer (score 0):

After some puzzlement, I can confirm that this is how you do it with a single line. The data here contains an extra column of units; I'm filtering out the 'Ratio' records, which I don't want to use. The key is to use the `.loc` method [described here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) with `.map`

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,'unit']!='Ratio','real'] = df.loc[df.loc[:,'unit']!='Ratio','nominal'] * df.loc[df.loc[:,'unit']!='Ratio','year'].map(factors)
```